# rxjs pipeline to filter documents based on conditions and return array

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, pipe, concatmap

In my Angular service I am trying to write a pipeline that would take a list of documents.  Filter them based on some conditions, for example property value must not be null, etc.  Then the document that are returned from filter, I want to make Api call and compare the value of a certain property in document.  If that passes, continue to next Api call and compare another property with the result of Api call.  If that passes, add the document to array.

At the end return the array of these valid documents.

I tried something like this.  But not sure if I am on the right track.  Please help.

```js
from(listOfDocs).pipe(
  .filter((doc: Doc) => {
    if (!doc.Name) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
   }),
  concatMap((doc: Doc) => {
        
    return this.myApiService.getDoc(...)
     // how do I get the document returned from Api and do a comparison on a property 
     // value
     // return document if valid otherwise skip to next document
  }),
  concatMap((doc: Doc) => {
        
    return this.mySecondApiCall.getDoc(...)
     // how do I get the document returned from Api and do a comparison on a property 
     // value
     // return document if valid otherwise skip to next document
  })
 // then finally add valid documents to array and return it
```

Comment: I’d break this in two and not go observable for the initial list (assuming that list is already available). Your filter won’t work like that btw, you’d need to map through your docs and then filter each item. After you have a list of valid docs, use a forkJoin to do the APi requests.

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks for replying.  I think you are right.  I had the same thought in mind. 
 I will try that out.  You say the filter wont work, but in the concatMap method I do get a doc reference with intellisense.  So I am assuming filter() passes me the doc.  I will test it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, something like this might be what you're looking for.

Each steps filters out any documents that don't meet the filter criteria. This assumes that `myApiService` and `mySecondApiCall` **always** both emit once and then complete. Otherwise you'd need `take(1)` before the filter to ensure this.

```ts
from(listOfDocs).pipe(

  filter((doc: Doc) => !!doc.name),
  concatMap((doc: Doc) => 
    this.myApiService.getDoc(/*...*/).pipe(
      filter(resp => doc.property1 === resp),
      map(_ => doc)
    )
  ),
  concatMap((doc: Doc) => 
    this.mySecondApiCall.getDoc(/*...*/).pipe(
      filter(resp => doc.property2 === resp),
      map(_ => doc)
    )
  ),
  toArray()

).subscribe(listOfDocs => 
  console.log(`These Docs have passed all 3 filters ${listOfDocs}`)
);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: I have one more question.  If I have for example a list of fileSections and want to get subSections for each fileSection and then insert into a map of type Map<string,Subsection[]>, is this the correct way?  I was wondering if there is a way to just to fill the map and return nothing. from(this.fileSections).pipe(
      mergeMap(fileSection => {
          return callApi.pipe(
            map( subsections => this.sections.set(fileSection.name, subsections))
          )
      })

Comment: Sounds like you want to fill the map as a side effect (without altering the stream of emissions). The operator for that is called `tap`.

Comment: I tried tap.  But that still returns an Observable<Subsections[]>.   from(this.fileSections).pipe( mergeMap(fileSection => callApi()), tap( subsections => this.sections.set(fileSection.name, subsections)) ). I want to return void.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're talking about, maybe start a new StackOverflow question with details. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help.  With your answer above you really helped me get better at forming the pipeline with rxjs operators.  I learned some key things from your example.

Comment: I posted a new question, whenever you get a chance please take a look.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146574/how-can-i-add-the-values-emitted-from-mergemap-to-a-map